# host web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I am working on asp.net C#.When i use visual studio 2010 web development server everythnig is working fine, but when i try to host my app on IIS server, the connectivity with the database is not properly maintained. e.g it says that the database is a read only database, whereas i m able to edit/insert whn i host the same app on web development server. I m using mssql server s database. my connection string is

`"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"`
plz help.

Comment: Access is denied is referring to some permission problem. Check permissions on the MDF file as well as on the directories. Are you local admin on this server?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the database directory is writeable by the appropriate user accounts, Network Service, etc, depending on the OS you're using?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..But I am not sure what you meant by checking the database directory..I am using MS Sql server 2008, and that creates only one file, namely Mydatabase.mdf. That seems to contain all the tables are views and all. I am using windows XP.

Comment: The directory that file is in needs write permissions. And the file